# Symbolically solving linear program

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I have been surprised that Mathematica cannot solve a linear program. Specifically, I have tried to solve the following problem:

```
Minimize[{x, 
    x >= 0.41 m + 1.12 n + .15 p - .9 e - .5 T && 
    x >=  2.35 n + 1.35 p - 2 e && x >= 2.35 n - 2 e - 2 T - .35 p}, p]
```

Is there some way to solve problems of this sort?

Comment: Try exact values not numeric.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there a way to convert all the numbers automatically?

Comment: Use `Rationalize`